# Using a table to add objects/images to a view

Tags: xcode, uitableview, view, nib, image

First off this is Xcode 4 iOS 5.0. Here is what I want to do. I have one view, we will call it view1, which has a button and when that button is pressed a different view with a table appears called tableView. I have multiple images I want to be in this table and when the image is selected, it would appear in view1. I have already researched all of this and just can not find the right material. The button and table are already working together and I can add the objects to the table, but getting those objects that I select to appear on view1 is what I am not understanding. I can not get the two nib files to work together, or Im going at it wrong.

Second question, guess this is similar, view1 displays an image that is selected from the photo library BUT is there a way to open the photo library, select the photo, and have it appear in a DIFFERENT nib view? Again this is getting the NIBs to work together. I would appreciate all the help I can get. (photo library and selection of photo already works so that code is not needed). Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [this](https://github.com/AalokParikh/ELCImagePickerController) example to get what you have described in the above question. But with some tweak in the delegate methods and hop you will get some direction for your problems, too.

Good Luck!

Happy Codding! :)

And need any help just ask for it, don't hesitate.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible from delegates in other class.